# converting array based on different id's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
Result=[{ 'Sum': 4580,'class': '01','pID': 1},
 { 'Sum': 580, 'class': '01','pID': 2},
 { 'Sum': 1280,'class': '01','pID': 3},
 { 'Sum': 5580,'class': '02','pID': 1},
 { 'Sum': 280, 'class': '02','pID': 2},
 { 'Sum': 380,'class': '02','pID': 3}]
```

I am trying to convert this array to

```
[{'class':'01','pID1':4580,'pID2':580,'pID3':1280},
 {'class':'02','pID1':5580,'pID2':280,'pID3':380}]
```

Comment: When you are tempted to name properties with numeric names like `pID2` and `pID3` you should consider an array instead: `pIDs = [4580, 580, 580]` Then access them with `pIDs[0]` `pIDs[1]`, .etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an accumulator object with each `class` as key. If the current `class` has not been added yet, create the key with the current `class` value. Else, add a new key `"pID"` + current `pID` with the value set to current `Sum`. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the `merged` object as an array

```js
const input = [{ 'Sum': 4580,'class': '01','pID': 1},
 { 'Sum': 580, 'class': '01','pID': 2},
 { 'Sum': 1280,'class': '01','pID': 3},
 { 'Sum': 5580,'class': '02','pID': 1},
 { 'Sum': 280, 'class': '02','pID': 2},
 { 'Sum': 380,'class': '02','pID': 3}]
 
const merged = input.reduce((acc, { Sum, class:c, pID }) => {
  acc[c] = acc[c] || { class: c }
  acc[c]["pID" + pID] = Sum;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

This is what the accumulator/`merged` object looks like:

```
{
  "01": {
    "class": "01",
    "pID1": 4580,
    "pID2": 580,
    "pID3": 1280
  },
  "02": {
    "class": "02",
    "pID1": 5580,
    "pID2": 280,
    "pID3": 380
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function below will do the transformation for you.

Pass in your data like `transform(Result);`

```js
function transform(result) {
   const map = {};

   result.forEach(data => {
     if (!map[data.class]) {
       map[data.class] = { 'class': data.class };
     }

     map[data.class]['pID' + data.pID] = data.Sum;
   });

   return Object.keys(map).map(key => map[key]); // return Object.values(map);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect the sums and return only the values.

```js
var data = [{ Sum: 4580, class: "01", pID: 1 }, { Sum: 580, class: "01", pID: 2 }, { Sum: 1280, class: "01", pID: 3 }, { Sum: 5580, class: "02", pID: 1 }, { Sum: 280, class: "02", pID: 2 }, { Sum: 380, class: "02", pID: 3 }],
    result = Array.from(data
        .reduce(
            (m, o) => m.set(o.class, Object.assign(m.get(o.class) || {}, { class: o.class, ['pID' + o.pID]: o.Sum })),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```